# Does Emacs have a standard function to insert or overwrite text depending of the state of overwrite-mode?

Tags: insert, overwrite

- Context: using Emacs 26.2

I would like to write Emacs Lisp code that inserts or over-types text depending of the state of the overwrite-mode.  I would call this function to insert text instead of the standard `insert` function.  When code uses the standard `insert` function while `overwrite-mode` is `t`, text is inserted and not overwritten.

I could write and use the following function, but I would have thought that such functionality would already be built-in Emacs.  I can't find it.  Does Emacs already provide a similar function?

```
(defun insert-or-overwrite (text)
  "Insert or overwrite text depending of overwrite-mode status."
  (when overwrite-mode
    (delete-char (length text)))
  (insert text))
```

Comment: Do you know why?  Is it because it's difficult to handle all cases?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is almost yes. `self-insert-command` is the command that is run for those keys that simply insert a character into the current buffer, and it handles overwrite correctly (and it handles the edge cases that you have forgotten in the code you wrote; I recommend taking a look at it yourself). Of course it's not really very convenient to use, since it doesn't take a string of text as an argument.

Comment: Thanks.  I know my code does not handle a single character.  It should check for it as in:   (defun insert-or-overwrite (text)
  "Insert or overwrite text depending of overwrite-mode status."
  (when overwrite-mode
    (if (stringp text)
        (delete-char (length text))
      (delete-char 1)))
  (insert text))     --- However I can't see how to invoke ``self-insert-command`` from code and pass it a string.  How would you call it to insert a single character?  And it's written in C, so that's not really an option unless I contribute one directly in Emacs.

Comment: I suppose that could be an edge case, if your function were called with a char instead of a string, but note carefully how `self-insert-command` handles double-wide characters, in both the input and the buffer.

Comment: I didn't think of multi-byte characters.  But even for non-ASCII, it only works for strings not characters. I just tried it with ``?ß`` as an input and I got it failing sequencep (223).   However attempting to overwrite "-ß-" worked fine.